# Linker Error QT 4.6 and VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, linker

Has anyone seen this before:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*thiscall QWidget::~QWidget(void)" (*_imp_??1QWidget@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Window@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z$0  window.obj

I have a bunch of these types of errors.

I am trying to use QT4.6 and Visual Studio 2008. Sorry I am still a beginner at this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the library and dll paths aren't set.

Start by trying to build and run the samples, the studio files with them should have all the necessary paths set.